# Microscopic Ohms Law Derivation

Tags: electric-current

I'm currently trying to understand the derivation of microscopic Ohm's Law. In the derivation it says that 
$$ \vec{E}^{}=  \vec{\nabla}^{}V $$

which I understands. And then it says that from that, we get this

$$ V = \int_{}^{}\vec{E}.\vec{ds} $$

And that's what I don't understand.

Comment: (1) That isn't Ohm's law, and (2) the fundamental theorem of vector calculus says that $\int_A^B (\nabla f) \cdot d\vec s = f(B)-f(A)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it like this:
$\vec{E}=-\nabla V$ is equivalent to $\langle E_x,E_y,E_z\rangle = -\langle \partial_xV,\partial_yV,\partial_zV \rangle$.

Then, we have $\Delta V=\int (\partial_xV dx+\partial_yVdy+\partial_zVdz)=-\int (E_xdx+E_ydy+E_zdz)=-\int\langle E_x,E_y,E_z \rangle\cdot\langle dx, dy, dz \rangle=-\int\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}$.

You may want to read up the wikipedia page for understanding what the concept of a gradient:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you. I understand gradient intuitively, it's just I'm getting a bit confused with the maths of it.